# Display items depending on date issued

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am getting a list of items from a feed URL as follows:

```ts
   getFeed(){
    return Observable.interval(5000)
      .mergeMap(() => this._http.get(this.feedUrl))
      .map(this.extractFeeds)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractFeeds(res: Response): Feed {
     let feeds = res.json();
     return feeds || { };
  }
```

And that is working fine. Now I wish to split these, depending on the `feed[].publishedDate`; if the time is within the last 5 minutes, then I wish to group these into a list I have:

```
  private latestFeeds: Feed[];
```

if not, then group these into another list I have:

```
  private olderFeeds: Feed[];
```

What is the best way to do it? In the actual service, or by using an `*ngIf` in the template? My HTML looks like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="feeds">
<div *ngFor="let feed of feeds | slice:0:9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="search-res well">
                <div>
                    <strong>Date Published: </strong>
                    {{feed.publishDate | date:'medium'}}
                </div>
                <a href="{{feed.link}}" target="_blank"><h4>{{feed.title}}</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My feedComponent.ts is as follows

```
  constructor(private _feedService:FeedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.getFeed();
 }

 getFeed() {
   this._feedService.getFeed()
     .subscribe( res => {
       this.feeds = res;
     })
 }
```

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: I'd probably start with neither; do the split in the component, and expose two properties to the template. Displaying the "latest" fields in this case seems like a display concern.

Comment: Im new to Angular.  Can you give me an example of how I can do an if/else statement in the code?  I also added my component in the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following code in the feed.component.cs

```
    var currentTimeMinus5Minutes = new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes() - 5);
    var elementDate = new Date(element.publishDate);
    if(elementDate.getTime() > currentTimeMinus5Minutes){
        this.breakingNewsFeeds.push(element);
    }
    else{
        this.otherFeeds.push(element);
    }
```

Thanks for all your help guys, especially jonsharpe who pointed me to the right direction.